# Storring data in web.config(custom section/appSettings element) vs storing it in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config

Why is it better to store data inside an `appSettings` element (or inside a custom section) of a `web.config` file than to store it in a class?

One argument would be that by using custom sections we don’t have to recompile code when we change data, but that’s a weak argument, especially if we’re using Web Sites, which get recompiled automatically whenever code changes!

Thank you

Comment: what kind of data are you referring to storing?

Comment: I know huge amounts of data shouldn't be stored inside classes or inside web.config, but besides that, does it matter what sort of data I want to store when deciding between web.config and class?

Answer (score 8):

Because you can change it on the fly and use it without regard to class structure. Your configuration can vary from each developers machine to staging to deployment environment by changing and maintaining a single file independently of the code, and you can take advantage of *.config masking with different areas of your site.

Hard coding anything configurable is a recipe for failure and it *absolutely* will bite you - this is just a matter of experience, if you don't believe it then you have but to wait a little while!

Comment: +! "Hard coding anything configurable is a recipe for failure"

Answer (score 1):

By putting settings into web.config, you have them all in a centralized location.

Also when deploying a web site, you might want to precompile it once. So you won't be able to change the source afterwards (without another recompilation).

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a concern of just recompiling the code, it's more about re-deploying the code.  Normally, you don't deploy code to the web server, you just deploy the binaries and aspx/html files.  If you hard-code your config data in the code, you'll have to rebuild and redeploy the library or application to get the change up to the server, which is a lot more work than just updating the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Putting data in the web.config file also allows the same code to be run in different environments with different environment-dependent data.  This can mean running the same website code in staging with a test database connection string and in the production environment with the production database connection string.  Or it could mean allowing the developers to configure the data for their own tests without changing any code, as 'annakata' mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a WHOLE lot easier to manage and update the settings.

If you're using Notepad to do your development and putting the code out on the server, I would agree that there is little benefit, but if you're using Visual Studio and you ***build*** your website and publish it, you're publishing the pre-compiled dlls and not just updating text source code (.cs or .vb files) on the server.   So when it comes time to update a setting at that point, anything in the web.config can be updated by simply modifying the text file, where as with other changes, you have to re-compile t whole web site and publish it.

And from experience, that becomes tricky when taking over after other developers that weren't careful about ensuring everything needed to make a web site work is in source control.  I'm now stuck with a web site where we can't update huge chunks of it because of (kindly putting it) non-standard practices in the past.

Being able to update something without re-publishing the site is a huge blessing in my situation, and you never know who the poor maintenance programmer will be that takes over on your code.

Be nice to him or her.  Make it easy to make simple changes.